# Case creation through Email after combining approx. 18 mailbox - Suggestion requested for Solutioning

Tags: apex-email-service

We are working to migrate our 18 mailboxes from different domains to one domain and business wants that there should be only one mailbox i.e support@yourcompany.com

Now, this is interesting ask, business also wants to have automatic case triaging. For example a company has 3 platforms, each platform has 6-7 modules and every module has around 4-5 services. so if any customer has any issue with one of the service and provide the details in mailbody like module and platform, the case created should be auto triaged to the specific service queue(we will create specific queues).

After it is assigned to the queue, it should be assigned to agent with that particular service skill.

Hope to get some suggestions.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: this looks like a use case for Service Cloud Einstein

Comment: Thanks @cropredy